# Subquery in mySQL , referring to a book by it's isbn rather than title

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, union

I need to , using a subquery approach, find the number of times the book with the title ‘Room’ was part of an order.

**relevant schema tables**

orderDetails(oNo, bookISBN, quantity)

book(isbn, title, authorID, genre, pubYear, publisher,
rrPrice, avgRating)

It appears in two orders and bookISBN and isbn are the primary and foreign key

I have tried

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM orderDetails
WHERE  'Room' in (SELECT title
                         FROM book)
```

Which returns 25, even though there are only two orders with the book Room. I can see why it is wrong but I can't figure out how I would call the book by it's ISBN (without just typing 323 as that would be a shortcut)

Comment: Please provide sample data.

Comment: Is using subquery necessary ? Is it some kind of homework ?

Comment: I know that there's debate about this kind of thing, but personally, I wouldn't use an ISBN as a primary key. My view is that the PK should have no meaning beyond the scope of the database - and, after all, a book sometimes has more than one ISBN!

Comment: Please clarify whether you want to consider only those books where `title` is **exactly** `'Room'` or **contains** `'Room'` in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM orderDetails
WHERE bookISBN in (SELECT isbn
                         FROM book where title = 'Room')
```

You can use the `Like` operator in subquery as well `%Room%` for title

Answer (score 0):

Your where clause either evaluates to true or false.  It is not correlated to the outer query, so:

- "true" means that all rows are returned (and counted)
- "false" means that no rows are returned (and counted)

You can fix this by using a correlation clause:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM orderDetails od
WHERE 'Room' IN (SELECT b.title FROM book b WHERE od.bookISBN = b.ISBN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normal Query, without using subquery:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1)
FROM 
    orderDetails od
    INNER JOIN book b ON b.isbn = od.bookISBN
WHERE
    b.title LIKE '%ROOM%'
```

Abnormal query, with inner query, I don't recommend this as this is unnecessary, but here we go:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1)
FROM 
    orderDetails od
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT isbn, title FROM book
    ) b ON b.isbn = od.bookISBN
WHERE
    b.title LIKE '%ROOM%
```

Even more abnormal query with subquery:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1)
FROM
    orderDetails od
WHERE
    od.bookISBN IN (SELECT isbn FROM book WHERE title like '%ROOM%')
```

TIPS: 
1. I have used `count(1)`, since, it doesn't make sense to count all the columns, so, instead, you can just count the successful entries to the condition and it will be faster.
2. Using a subquery limits the capability of the compiler, hence, I advise against it.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion Join Would be better:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM orderDetails LEFT JOIN book ON isbn=bookISBN
WHERE  title LIKE N'%Room%'
```

but if you must use sub query:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM orderDetails
WHERE  bookISBN in (SELECT isbn
                    FROM book 
                    WHERE title LIKE N'%Room%')
```

no matter which way we use we always must use common field to get

Comment: These queries cannot decide whether they are INNER JOINs or LEFT JOINs

Comment: left join would be better while it need only number of orders

Comment: @Strawberry is right the first query will run as a `INNER JOIN` instead.. The filter condition with a `LEFT JOIN` should be in the `ON` clause instead.. it should be `LEFT JOIN book ON isbn=bookISBN AND title LIKE N'%Room%'`...